# Template specialisation inherit from specific subclass

Tags: c++, templates

```
class Base { ... };
class Derived1 : Base { ... };
class Derived2 : Base { ... };

template <> class BaseDecorator<Base> : **SpecificDerived** { ... };
```

Is it possible for **SpecificDerived** to reference the particular Derived class that is being used? Such that

```
BaseDecorator<Derived1> bd-d1;
```

Would instantiate a BaseDecorator that inherits from Derived1?

The problem has come about because I need to provide a decorator for a library class and all its derivations, but want to keep the code as dry as possible.

Thanks!

Comment: The question is somewhat unclear, but I can't think of any situation where "BaseDecorator<Derived1> bd-d1;" would be valid C++ syntax.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Do you mean invalid syntax because of one of the classes? Or merely the syntax of the declaration? What would be wrong with that?

Comment: Try defining a stub template with this name, like "`template<typename T> class BaseDecorator {};`". Then go ahead and write this declaration verbatim: "`BaseDecorator<Derived1> bd-d1;`", and see how much your C++ compiler likes this. Spoiler: not really. This is, obviously, not valid C++.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I assume you're referring to the hyphen. As for the rest of it,
`class Base {};
class Derived : Base {};
template<typename T> class BaseDecorator {};
int main() { BaseDecorator<Derived> bdd1; }`
Compiles fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want your BaseDecorator to inherit from specific Derived class.

If that is the case, You may do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class Base {
    public:
    virtual void f1() {
        std::cout << "Base::f1" << std::endl;   
    }
};

class Derived1 : public Base {
    public:
    void f1() override {
        std::cout << "Derived1::f1" << std::endl;   
    }
};

class Derived2 : public Base {
    public:
    void f1() override {
        std::cout << "Derived2::f1" << std::endl;   
    }
};

class Derived3 {
    public:
    void f1() {
        std::cout << "Derived3::f1" << std::endl;   
    }
};

template <typename T,
          typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value>::type >
class BaseDecorator;

template <typename T>
class BaseDecorator<T>: public T {
    public:
    void f2() {
        T::f1();
    }
};

int main() {
    BaseDecorator<Derived1> bd1;
    bd1.f2();

    BaseDecorator<Derived2> bd2;
    bd2.f2();

    //BaseDecorator<Derived3> bd3; // Compilation fails !!!
    //bd3.f2(); // Compilation fails !!!

    return 0;   
}
```

Output:

```
Derived1::f1
Derived1::f2
```

Comment: That's almost what I'm looking for except that BaseDecorator<T> should only accept Base / Derived classes as template arguments. Ie a BaseDecorator should not be constructible from any arbitrary class, but only from Base and its subclasses.

Comment: @BenHogan I have updated my answer. Have a look at it. If you liked it, please mark it as accepted.